# Trouble with php code after moving from old windows host to new host running linux.

Tags: php, linux, windows

Recently we moved our site from old windows based host running an old php to new linux host running latest php/mysql.

I managed to fix quite few problems but there are two that are eluding me.

First one are non working numbers to switch to new "page" in our inventory.

e.g. -> http://adepto.hr/adepto_promotivni_artikli.php?kat=10&start=0

When you click on any of the above number nothing happens.  It's same on all other categories.  Here is page code.  As I said, I managed to fix some errors that were caused by outdated code, but can't sort this one out.

http://pastebin.com/fbxZdgS5

Second one are the Croatian letters which are not showing correctly. ( e.g. čćšđž). 
I'v tried declaring it in php files but without luck.  What would be the correct way to declare/define this character set ?

Thank you, 
Saturnij

Comment: The problem with the characters can be solved by using this meta-tag: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8" />

Comment: And for your other problem; I think you need the line $start = $_GET['start']; somewhere before line 178.

Comment: You application is _wide_ _open_ to sql injection.

Comment: I would recommend, that you take this script offline, as long as you have some serious security issues in there. Dont post your real URL next time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where `$start` is instantiated. Looks like you're missing a `$start = $_GET['start']`

You should also be saving your PHP files as UTF-8 rather than ISO-8859-1 if you want good character set support.

Comment: Declaring $start helped with page numbers, thank you. Bum I'm still having problems with charset. I' declared it as lex suggested in above post but it still not showing characters.

Comment: better use the header()-command to set the charset: header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: As a beginner, I would not start with UTF8, as there are some scenarios, where the charset is badly supported by php. Better start with a pure 8-bit charset like ISO-8859-1 (or ISO-8859-15 for €-sign support)

Comment: Hi, I'v noticed when I run mysql query on my server e.g       mysql> SELECT * FROM kategorije WHERE ID=25;
+---------+---------+-----------+----+
| naziv   | katBroj | mainKatID | ID |
+---------+---------+-----------+----+
| Ko�ulje |      25 |        19 | 25 |             
+---------+---------+-----------+----+                               I get result which is "broken" or to be exact, it doesn't show correct letters.   I'v checked db with phpmyadmin and all values are correctly writen in there.  Don't know how  to google this problem up.  Why is this happening ?